# Why my custom table cell view layout in Storyboard is different scale when compare in simulator

Tags: ios, swift

I am using XCode 6 and I create a Table View for my application using swift.
And I have a custom layout for my TableCell View. In the Size inspector, both the TableView and my TableCellView have a width of 600.

And I use story board to layout my TableCell View. It has an UIImageView and 2 Lablels:
[image]

As you can see from the above screenshot, my UIImageView has a width of 300 and it should only takes up half of the table cell.

But when I run in of simulator, It almost takes up the whole cell.

![enter image description here][2]

Can you please tell me why this happens? Are the TableView width and Table Cell View are using different scale?

Comment: are you using autoLayout..?

Comment: How can I make sure?

Comment: in to storyBoard :-->show the file inspectore there is Autolayout check box and use size class checkbox is checked?